# How to kill a java thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I google the solution for killing a java thread. And there exists two solutions:

1. set a flag
2. using Thread.interrupt

But both of them are not suitable for me. In my thread, I call a third-party api which takes a long time to complete. and I want to let the user to cancel this thread if it takes too much time.

So how can I kill this thread ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to kill it, just let them commit suicide...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Thread.interrupt()` is the only safe method which is generally applicable. You can of course use other application-level signals (such as a conditional check on a volatile variable) to self-terminate. Other methods (such as all the deprecated Thread.xx methods) can pollute your application's state in non-deterministic ways, and would require reloading all application state.

Comment: Thread.interrupt is only half the story, the thread you are interrupting must support an interrupt policy that uses the interrupt flag... its that flag that call Thread.interrupt will reset.

Comment: Most of the times Thread.interrupt doesn't kill the thread instead the Thread goes on continuing. In such a situation what would be the best solution.

Comment: @Kathir: Thread.interrupt sends an InterruptedException to the thread when blocked. It is your job to catch and shut down appropriately.

Comment: @YannRamin and how would you shut it down appropriately?

Comment: Yes Ramin, please elaborate?

Comment: @NiteshVerma Simply returning out of the run() method of the underlying Runnable will destroy the thread. There is no requirement to join() threads, unless your synchronization requires it.

Comment: thanks, i worked well. Moreover i see that this thing was quite conceptual and can be done easily if your basic concepts on threads are fine

Comment: You have not answered the question. Question was how to kill thread that is hanging due to shitty 3rd party code (which can not be fixed). Best option here is to use Future with timeout and wrap shitty code into Callable.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, you could call the deprecated `Thread.stop()` method.  But beware that this could result in your application behaving in unexpected and unpredictable ways ... depending on what the third party library is actually doing.  `Thread.stop()` and friends are fundamentally unsafe.

The best solution is to modify the 3rd-party library to respond to Thread.interrupt.  If you cannot, then ditch it and find / use a better library.

Comment: Future + Callable

Comment: That approach doesn't allow you to forcibly stop a thread.  The `Future.cancel` method uses `Thread.interrupt()`, and we've already been told that `Thread.interrupt()` is not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the *call a third-party api which takes a long time* into a `Callable<DataTypeReturnedBy3rdPartAPI>` and then execute it with a `SingleThreadExecutor` specifying a **timeout**.

Following this approach, the thread will be ***killed*** if the *call to third party API* takes longer than `timeOut`,  here is some code to exemplify what I am saying:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 try {
   //================= HERE ==================
   Future<Boolean> job = executor.submit(thirdPartyCallable);
   executor.awaitTermination(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS);      
   if(!job.isDone())
     logger.debug("Long call to 3rd party API didn't finish");
   //=========================================
 } catch (Exception exc) {
     exc.printStackTrace();      
 } finally {
     if(!executor.isShutdown() )
       executor.shutdownNow();
 }

}  

private static Callable<Boolean>  thirdParytCallable = new Callable<Boolean>() {
  public Boolean call() throws Exception {
    //Call to long 3rd party API
    //.......
    for(long i = 0;i<99999991999999L;i++) {
      Thread.sleep(10L);// Emulates long call to 3rd party API
      System.out.print(".");
    }
    return Boolean.valueOf(true);//Data from 3rd party API
  }
};
```

Comment: Joshua Bloch's 'Effective Java "2nd Edition' Item 68: Prefer executors and tasks to threads

Answer (score 1):

Spawn a separate process and kill it using OS facilities.  You'll have to call into "C" to do it but it won't be much code.   You didn't say what OS you are running on.

Comment: well, this should work, but it's too heavy for me, and it can increase the complexity of integration and share data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Thread.stop()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29), but [at your own risk](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html). Optimally, the API you're calling should have a way to interrupt the operation if needed (which is what [Thread.interrupt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) is for if the API itself does not provide a cleaner way to interrupt its progress, have you tried it?).

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the `stop` method on the Thread object but it is strongly recommended that you don't. Read this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Do you have the freedom to make minor changes to the API? Is this blocking call CPU bound or IO bound?  If it is IO bound and if you have access to the underlying socket/remote communication object, closing that object can do wonders. It is at least better than *stopping* the thread.

Answer (score 0):

In **java.util.concurrent.FutureTask**, the mechanism of cancellation by timeout is acted as throwing **java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException**.

You may check out this as if there are something to be interrupted automatically by timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Thread.stop()` is (rightly) deprecated, generally this is accomplished by setting a flag to true.  Something like this:

Calling Class:

```
...
workListExecutor.stop()
...
```

WorkListExecutor.class:

```
boolean running = true;

void stop(){
  running = false;
}

void run(){
  while (running) {
    ... do my stuff ...
  }
}
```

This is assuming your thread has some kind of main loop (usually the case).
If the code in your loop is too big, you can periodically check if `running` is still `true`, and bail out if it's not.

This has the advantage that you can still clean up when you're done.  The thread will be killed automatically when your run method finishes.