# How to terminate a thread like this in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to kill a java thread ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121470/how-to-kill-a-java-thread)

I have threads in my app like the below one.

How can I terminate them?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {

    // do it…

  }    
}).start();
```

**Edit:**

**Solution:**

```
Class Memory{

    static Runnable last;

}
```

This will save our Thread in a var.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
                Memory.last = this;
        // do it…

      }    
    }).start();
```

now in any part you want stop:

```
Memory.last.wait(); //will pause but next new thread will terminate it (garbage collector do this );
```

Comment: in general you have to in some way tell the thread to kill itself, killing a thread from the outside directly is inherently unsafe.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your run() method, you can periodically call `interrupted()` to test whether the thread is interrupted, and then either exit silently or throw an InterruptedException. To stop the thread you can call it's `interrupt()` method. See the [Java tutorial in interrupts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) for more info.

Comment: you can call Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() and not Thread.interrupted() if you don't want to reset the flag

Answer (score 0):

They'll stop running  when it's run method is done. Depending on what you put in that method they'll stop immediately or would run forever.

If they have a loop you have to change that thread condition to false.