# Kill an uncooperative thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, kill, interrupt

Following piece is from a JUnit testcase that tests 4 different implementations of `Sorter`. It invokes the only method `Sorter` has viz `sort()`.

I want to kill the sorting process if it takes longer than say 2 seconds (Because I don't care for any implementation that takes longer than 2 seconds to `sort()` say 500000 `Integers`).

I'm new the Java multi-threading and after looking at all other threads ( [How to kill a java thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121470/how-to-kill-a-java-thread) and a few others) on SO, I figured following as solution to my problem. **Question is, would it work consistently, or could there be any issues?** I don't care abt the array or it's contents as `reset()` would reset it's contents.

Reason why I call it uncooperative is because `s.sort()` is out of my control.

```
protected E[] arr;
@Test
public void testSortTArray() {
    boolean allOk = true;
    for (Sorter s : TestParams.getSorters()) {
        System.out.println("Testing: " + s.getName() + " with " + arrayLenToTestWith + " elems of type "
                + classOfElemType.getName());
        reset();
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        MyThread test = new MyThread(s, arr);
        test.start();
        try {
            test.join(TestParams.getTimeThreshold());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (test.isAlive())
            test.interrupt();

        if (!test.isInterrupted()) {
            System.out.println("Time taken: " + ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / (1000000)) + "ms");
            if (!isSorted(arr)) {
                allOk = false;
                System.err.println(s.getName() + " didn't sort array.");
            }
        } else {
            allOk = false;
            System.err.println(s.getName() + " took longer than .");
        }
    }
    assertTrue("At least one algo didn't sort the array.", allOk);
}

public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private Sorter s;
    private E[] arr;

    public MyThread(Sorter s, E[] arr) {
        this.s = s;
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        s.sort(arr);
    }
}
```

**--- edit: answer ---**

Based on comments from everyone:

- No. What I'm doing is not safe as `Thread.interrupt()` will not suspend the thread, it'll just set it's interrupted state, which if not checked by the thread's `run()` implementation, is useless.

  - In this case the next Sorter's sort() would be called on the same array (which is still being sorted by the old "interrupted" thread), thus making things unsafe.
- One option is to create a separate `Process` instead of a `Thread`. A `Process` can be killed.

  - Obviously the parameter passing isn't easy in this case as it involves some IPC.

Comment: +1, can have what you desire, but the solution is interesting. Curiously I am expecting if  you will post an answer or somebody else. I know 2 methods :) it is expected to "not possible to kill hava threads" , it is possible to do what you need: multiple solutions!

Comment: Could you get away with orphaning it?  Set its priority to the lowest possible level and forget about it?  You can then start another sort, if you wish, and the old one should not interfere much.

Comment: @ Everyone: Please do comment/edit if anything I wrote above (--edit: answer--) is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may have seen from the other questions you mention, it isn't possible to reliably stop a Java thread without its cooperation, because `interrupt()` ony works if the thread tests for it (deliberately or inadvertently).

However, it is possible to kill a [process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). If you spawn each sorting algorithm in a separate process, then you can kill it forcibly.

The downside is that interacting with the process is significantly harder than interacting with a thread, since you don't have shared variables.

Comment: Thanks. Though everyone gives correct answers, accepted this one as it actually provides an alternative using `Process` object.

Answer (score 3):

Without a thread's cooperation, there is no reliable and safe way to stop it. With a thread's cooperation, you can interrupt or stop a thread using the mechanism it supports. Threads just don't provide this kind of isolation ... you have to use multiple processes.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a case for Thread.stop(). Do read the disclaimer in the javadoc, though, in particular:

> **Deprecated**. This method is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread with Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked ThreadDeath exception propagating up the stack). If any of the objects previously protected by these monitors were in an inconsistent state, the damaged objects become visible to other threads, potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior. Many uses of stop should be replaced by code that simply modifies some variable to indicate that the target thread should stop running. The target thread should check this variable regularly, and return from its run method in an orderly fashion if the variable indicates that it is to stop running. If the target thread waits for long periods (on a condition variable, for example), the interrupt method should be used to interrupt the wait.

Comment: You may be right.  In this particular case, where a sort is running on an array, it may be safe.

Comment: If the thread is presumed to be well-behaved and cooperative, there is no reason to kill it -- the thread will stop when asked.  If this presumption doesn't hold, Thread.stop() isn't safe.

Comment: It's not well-behaved and cooperative.  That is exactly the OP's problem!  In this case, assuming an in-place sort, with no extra memory allocations, (as may be required by, say, a merge-sort), this may well be a valid, and safe, answer.  I'm going to upvote it, for understanding that this may well be the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> would it work consistently, or could there be any issues?

It would work except that you need to handle the thread interrupt correctly.  `thread.interrupt()` will only work if the `sort` method supports it.  I suspect that the method will not be calling `Thread.sleep()`, `wait()`, or other such methods.  Therefore it needs to test to see if it has been interrupted as it does its processing:

```
 while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     // do sort stuff
 }
```

If it doesn't do that then interrupting the thread will not stop the processing.  I would certainly add another `test.join();` after the interrupt to make sure that the thread finishes before you start another sort operation.

Comment: Is there any problem with setting its priority to the lowest possible and forgetting about it?  Not tried that in Java - feasible?

Comment: Even with the lowest setting the thread will consume cycles which will affect the other performance measurements @Martin.   And if there are multiple CPUs it will continue to run in another processor which would affect timing as well.

Comment: Only those left over after every other higher-priority thread is blocked?

Comment: I'm not saying there will be no impact, just not very much.  If no other alternative solution will work, this may be enough.  May be worth trying, especially if the only alternative is to communicate the array to another process:(

Comment: The way the priority works is that if T1 has priority 1 and T2 has priority 10, then T2 runs 10 times more often but T1 _does_ run.  You can't starve a thread by setting priority @MartinJames.

Comment: Depends on the scheduling algorithm.  Many such don't allow any CPU to be allocated to those threads that are ready, but cannot run because there are more, or the same, higher-priority ready threads than there are cores.  Some allow the bubbling-up of lower priority threads after some time, or apply some other anti-starvation algorithm, but setting the priority to a low value does make a significant difference to its impact on higher-priority threads.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of this @Martin because that's not my experience.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks guys, I would take it that the thread would still continue to get cycles. So what I'm doing is not safe as the old thread would continue to sort the same array, which is now being sorted by the newer thread/algorithm.

Comment: That's correct @thekashyap.  Not only would the old sorts be taking CPU but they would be working on the same sort list.

Comment: 'I don't care abt the array or it's contents as reset() would reset it's contents' - use another array - just allocate another one!