# How do I stop a thread from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am making a Skype like program.  Say I have 2 calls going that would mean I have 4 threads going.  I would have 2 threads that accept the users and then 2 more threads that handle the users messages etc... I made it to where if there is less than 2 users in the call it ends but how do I end one of the accept threads when there are 2 running and how do I tell one of the two to stop.  Is there a way that I can use the index number of the thread to stop it?

Comment: show what you tried so far

Comment: send the recieving thread a signal to end. All your threads are waiting for an input, so send them a message to signal them to end their jobs. As the others say, post your code you have to get into more detail

Comment: You could make the two threads store the reference of one another and try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194545/how-to-stop-a-java-thread-gracefully)

Comment: Having 4 threads per call is not a great idea in terms of scalability.  Java threads are relatively expensive.

Comment: Better duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121470/how-to-kill-a-java-thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to store your threads in variables (or an array) and to use [Interrupts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) to signal from one thread to another that it should stop. The thread you're signalling to then needs to handle the event.